# My REST API consumer app keeps hitting whitelabel error page

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, consumer

I have a Spring boot app that I added a rest API to. It works great when I use it with just my "Movies App". However, I have created a second app that needs to consume the rest API for two endpoints.

1. The films released in a particular year
2. The films directed by a particular director

I am working on the first at the moment and while earlier it was hitting a not found error, I fixed that and now I am just getting whitelabel error. It doesn't seem to be consuming the data. I'm not sure if I have just typed something wrong or if my entire approach is incorrect.

So when I run my consumer application at the same time as my Movies project, I should then be able to go to my browser and put in localhost:8080/api/films{releaseYear} and it should return all the films for that year on the page. So for example if releaseYear was 2015, I would put in localhost:8080/api/films/2015 and see the movies stored in my database that were released that year in Json.

```
My domain (Film.class) 
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Director {
    private int directorId;
    private String directorFirstName;
    private String directorSurname;
    private List<Film> films = new ArrayList<>(); 
    
    }
```

My FilmController in the rest consumer:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class FilmController {
    @GetMapping("/films/{releaseYear}")
    public String showFilmsByYear(@PathVariable(name="releaseYear") int releaseYear, Model model)
    {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String URL="http://localhost:8080/api/films/{releaseYear}";
            ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Film>> listOfFilms = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Film>>(){};
            ResponseEntity<List<Film>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, listOfFilms );
            List<Film> films = responseEntity.getBody();
            log.info(responseEntity.getHeaders().toString());
            model.addAttribute("films", films);
            return "films";
        }
        catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {   
            model.addAttribute("exception", ex); //exception isnt handled because hitting whitelabel
            return "notfound";
        }
        
    }
```

My FormObject:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FilmForm {

    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    private String filmName;
    //add minimum year and max year (won't always be 2020, but can't allow films that are further then current year)
    @PastOrPresent
    @NotBlank
    @Min(1888)
    private int releaseYear;
    @NotEmpty
    private Director director;
    
}
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <div th:insert="fragments.html :: head"></div>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div th:insert="fragments.html :: menu"></div>
            <h1><span th:text="#{films.heading}"></span></h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th th:text="#{films.id}"></th>
                <th th:text="#{films.filmName}"></th>
                <th th:text="#{films.directorFirstName}"></th>
                <th th:text="#{films.directorSurname}"></th>
                <th th:text="#{films.releaseYear}"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="film,iterationCount : ${films}" th:class="${iterationCount.even}? 'even'" th:object="${film}"  >           
                <td th:text="*{filmId}"></td>
                <td th:text="*{filmName}"></td>
                <td th:text="*{director.directorFirstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="*{director.directorSurname}"></td>
                <th th:text="*{releaseYear}"></th>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </main>
    </body>
    <footer th:insert="fragments.html :: footer">
    </footer>
</html>
```

It shouldn't need the form because its not using the html, but I just thought I would include for clarity's sake.

The controller I am trying to reach in my Movies project is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestControllerDir{
    @Autowired
    FilmService filmService;
    @Autowired
    DirectorService directorService;


    @GetMapping("directors")
    public List<Director> myRestDirectors(){
        return directorService.listInAlphabeticalOrder();
        }
    
    @GetMapping("filmsByDirector/{id}") 
    public List<Film> myRestFilms(@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
        return directorService.findDirector(id).getFilms(); //returns the films directed by a particular director
    }
    
    @GetMapping("viewFilmsByYear/{releaseYear}") 
    public List<Film> myRestFilmsYear(@PathVariable("releaseYear") int releaseYear)
    {
        return filmService.findFilmsByReleaseYear(releaseYear); //returns the films released in a particular year
    }
```

Comment: can you say what **exactly** is not working, it isn't clear

Comment: @JAsgarov Sorry! So when I run my consumer application at the same time as my Movies project, I should then be able to go to my browser and put in http://localhost:8080/api/films/{releaseYear} and it should return all the films for that year. So for example if releaseYear was 2015, I would put in http://localhost:8080/api/films/2015 and see the movies stored in my database that were released that year.

Comment: your `@GetMapping("/films/{releaseYear}")` doesn't include `api` in it

Comment: Where is the controller responsible for `/api/films{releaseYear}`?

Comment: I tried adding this to @GetMapping and the same issue happens with it. Also just tried @RequestMapping("/api") undereath my@Controller annotation and didn't work either.

Comment: It's in the Controller package of my consumer project. The consumer project is running on port 9090, and the spring on 8080. http://localhost:8080/api/viewfilmsbyyear/ (i edited it to ensure it could tell the difference from the ref to my html pages) gives a not found error. http://localhost:9090/api/viewfilmsbyyear/ gives a whitelabel error. My console error now reads as "Not enough variable values available to expand 'releaseYear' after my last try to load it in my browser.

Comment: 1) it would be more useful to show the controller you are trying to reach 2)if port is 9090 you should change `String URL="http://localhost:8080/api/films/{releaseYear}";` to `String URL="http://localhost:9090/api/films/{releaseYear}";` 3) Of course it does you need to path in the year but I can't tell you how because I can't see the controller that we are talking about (the receiving one)

Comment: I have added the controller to the original post. Thanks for not giving up already on helping! 9090 brings a similar error.

Comment: ok now that I see the controller try changing String URL to `String URL="http://localhost:9090/api/viewFilmsByYear/" + releaseYear;`

Comment: Didn't work with 9090, but when I put in 8080 it does! Thank you!

Comment: lol happy it worked out

Comment: Do you want to post it as an answer and Ill mark it the right one? That was a lot of work on your part there, for something that I clearly read through dozens of times.